# Retrieving and Parsing JSON

Tags: android, json, web-services

What's the easiest way to retrieve JSON from a web-service and to parse it? Without using any additional plug-ins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the standard procedure then you need to use `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` to parse responses. However, it is fuzzy and cumbersome when your response string contains a complex structure. In order to deal such complex responses its better to off the parsing to [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) or any other library.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best way to retreive JSON data and parsing it, i have used it in my project and it works totally well. Check out this [Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php) (source code also available).
If you are using JSON, you will definitely need Google gson library to convert Java Objects into their JSON representation. You can download it from [here](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.code.gson/gson/1.7.1).

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look here: http://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/AsyncAPI

Everything is explained, with the code samples you need.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should give you a starting point, just use it in an activity/service class. Its gets data from a URL (webservice), and converts it into a JSON object you can use.

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder =  new  StringBuilder();
HttpClient client =  new  DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new  HttpGet(***Put your web service URL here ***)
try
{
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    int  statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
    if (statusCode == 200)
    {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream content = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new  BufferedReader(
        new  InputStreamReader(content));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
           stringBuilder.append(line);
        }
     }
} 
catch (ClientProtocolException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
     e.printStackTrace();
}

//Turn string JSON into object you can process
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(stringBuilder.toString());
for  (int  i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
{
     //Get Each element
     JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i); 
     //Do stuff
}
```